# Failed attempt to relate a .csv file of 400 records to a single record in a point data layer

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, csv, relates

I have the Provincial Groundwater Monitoring Network as a point feature of 39 monitoring wells which includes an attribute for WELL ID. Each monitoring well then has a corresponding .csv file with 400 records of water level fluctuations.

I was wondering how I could relate the one well point to the many water level readings within a .csv file?

The WELL_ID field in the point layer is a String with a length of 254 however the corresponding field in the .csv file is a string with a length of 255. I have tried adding a field to the point layer with exactly the same name, type and length, however ArcMap 10 defaults the new string field to a length of 254.

Is there something I am doing wrong or is there something I could try differently.

sneely1

Comment: Which software are you using? If you are using ArcGIS, I think you need to convert the file into a DB from the CSV to do relates properly

Comment: I am using ArcMap 10. I will try that thanks

Comment: the water level records are named W00006-1.csv for example, so i am getting and error that the name contains invalid characters. is there an easy way in model builder to rename my 39 .csv files to W00006_1 ?

Comment: You can batch rename these on the command line.  Make a back up first. Then just open a cmd in that directory and run this:  for /f "tokens=* delims= " %i in ('dir /b "*.csv"') do Set LIST=%i& set LIST | ren "%~fi" "%LIST:-=_%"

Comment: I use filerenamer to handle that stuff. Then make sure your field names dont have any symbols or other items (spaces). Don't worry about the column width. You need a one to many join.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having 39 tables and trying to relate them individually, it sounds like what you want to do is combine/[denormalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) your various CSV files into one. Then simply import that into a geodatabase table or DBF and relate it to your point layer. If the filename is significant you could add it as a column to the combined CSV file.

You might be able to do this simply using the ArcToolbox [Merge](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000055000000) tool, but if you want a bit more flexibility (such as adding the filename as a column like I mentioned), the `merge_csv_files` function in the following Python script, which makes use of the very handy [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module, can do this for you.

The script, if run on its own as written, will run through a standalone test case (the `if __name__ == "__main__"` section) to demonstrate its use (see output below). Feel free to adapt it to your needs. For example you could `import` it as a module or copy-paste the `merge_csv_files` function into your own script.

```py
import os, sys, csv, pprint, tempfile

def merge_csv_files(input_csv_files, output_csv_file, filename_column=None):
    """
    Merges each of the CSV files specified by the input_csv_files sequence into
    the output_csv_file, optionally mapping the filename (minus extension) of
    each input_csv_file into a new column specified by filename_column.
    """
    with open(output_csv_file, "wb") as fo:
        w = None
        for i, csvfile in enumerate(input_csv_files):
            if filename_column:
                filename = os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(csvfile)[0])
            with open(csvfile, "rb") as fi:
                r = csv.DictReader(fi)
                if filename_column:
                    r.fieldnames.append(filename_column)
                if i < 1:
                    w = csv.DictWriter(fo, r.fieldnames)
                    w.writerow(dict((fn,fn) for fn in r.fieldnames)) # Python 2.6
                    ## w.writeheader() # Python 2.7+
                for row in r:
                    if filename_column:
                        row[filename_column] = filename
                    w.writerow(row)
        return output_csv_file

def write_csv_file(csv_file, rows):
    """Writes the input rows to the output csv_file."""
    with open(csv_file, "wb") as f:
        w = csv.writer(f)
        w.writerows(rows)
    return csv_file

def pprint_csv_file(csv_file):
    """Reads the input csv_file and pretty-prints its contents."""
    with open(csv_file, "rb") as f:
        r = csv.DictReader(f)
        pprint.pprint(r.fieldnames)
        for row in r:
            pprint.pprint([row[key] for key in r.fieldnames])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Get the path to the user's temporary files directory
    tempdir = tempfile.gettempdir()

    # Create a temporary CSV file for testing
    testcsv1 = write_csv_file(
        os.path.join(tempdir, "W00006-1.csv"),
        [["WELL_ID", "WATER_LEVEL"],
         [1, 50.5],
         [2, 60.5],
         [3, 70.5]])

    # Create another temporary CSV file for testing
    testcsv2 = write_csv_file(
        os.path.join(tempdir, "W00006-2.csv"),
        [["WELL_ID", "WATER_LEVEL"],
         [4, 55.5],
         [5, 65.5],
         [6, 75.5]])

    # Merge the two CSV files
    testmergecsv = merge_csv_files(
        [testcsv1, testcsv2],
        os.path.join(tempdir, "WELL_WATER_LEVELS.csv"),
        "FILE_NAME")

    # Print all three CSV files
    pprint_csv_file(testcsv1)
    pprint_csv_file(testcsv2)
    pprint_csv_file(testmergecsv)

    # Clean up temporary files
    [os.remove(f) for f in [testcsv1, testcsv2, testmergecsv]]
```

Example test output:

```
['WELL_ID', 'WATER_LEVEL']
['1', '50.5']
['2', '60.5']
['3', '70.5']
['WELL_ID', 'WATER_LEVEL']
['4', '55.5']
['5', '65.5']
['6', '75.5']
['WELL_ID', 'WATER_LEVEL', 'FILE_NAME']
['1', '50.5', 'W00006-1']
['2', '60.5', 'W00006-1']
['3', '70.5', 'W00006-1']
['4', '55.5', 'W00006-2']
['5', '65.5', 'W00006-2']
['6', '75.5', 'W00006-2']
```

The merged CSV file can be imported into a geodatabase table and related to your points feature class on `WELL_ID`. Actually in 10.1 you can relate to the CSV file directly without having to import it to a GDB table. Not sure about 10.0. For best performance, you'll probably want to import it to a file geodatabase and create attribute indices, however.